# Parallax scrolling choppy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a nice parallax scrolling effect for my website, and as long as I scroll the page using scrollbar it seems nice. But when I use keyboard of mouse scroll wheel - it's really choppy and laggy. Here's a portion of JS that's responsible for the parallax.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 600 && $(document).scrollTop() < 2500){
         var temp =  100 - ($(document).scrollTop() - 1200) / 8;
         var bonus = '50% ' + temp + '%';
         document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundPosition = bonus;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why is it choppy? I tried to resize the background-image to a smaller one, but that doesn't seem to be an issue here and therefore I'm seriously out of mana, don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also tried not to reposition background, but make a img, positioned absolutely and fiddle with the 'top' value, but with no luck. Animation still wasn't smooth.

Comment: Do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

i came across the same issue and found a neat trick to solve this.
"The last developer" found out you have to fix the background position and work against the scrolling direction:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 600 && $(document).scrollTop() < 2500){
         var temp =  100 - ($(document).scrollTop() - 1200) / 8;
         var bonus = '50% ' + temp*-1 + '%';
         document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundPosition = bonus;
    }
}
```

Use this css for your div

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

This definetly feels a lot smoother to me.
Source: [The Last Developer](http://thelastdeveloper.tumblr.com/post/20536873534/fix-parallax-jumping-jerky-hinky-jinky-scrolling-on)

Comment: This totally worked on a random site I was asked to check out why the parallax was choppy

Answer (score 3):

The scrolling is choppy because the input is choppy. Scrolling with the keyboard or mouse wheel makes the page *jump*.

If you want a nice transition I would recommend using CSS3 transitions.

They're surprisingly easy to set up and are *plugable*; you can pop them onto an existing (choppy) transition and it suddenly becomes fluid.

I'm not 100% sure you can put a transition on `background-position`, but if you can this is how you'd do it:

```
transition: .15s ease-in-out;
transition-property: background-position;
```

For compatibility add:

```
-webkit-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .15s ease-in-out;

-webkit-transition-property: background-position;
-moz-transition-property: background-position;
-o-transition-property: background-position;
```

Of course there are many more options and bells and whistles, but this should get you started.

Comment: Yeah, it is smooth, but I could get the same effect using jquery's animate function. But that's not the point. I can see that background repositioning is tad after I scrolled to a different progress. I want it to be instant. If I wasn't clear about what I wanted, than I'm sorry. A fine trick though - I'll definitely find a  good use for it.

Comment: If you use a different easing you might get a snappier feel, maybe `easy-out`. Transitions are preferred over animations because transitions can be hardware accelerated.

Answer (score 0):

I was glad to find a quick and easy fix to this. Installing this smooth scrolling plugin makes mouse scrolling super smooth and eliminates juttery/choppy parallax problems. http://bassta.bg/2013/05/smooth-page-scrolling-with-tweenmax/